# Opposite of "Pick" in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to compose a type, which, unlike `Pick`, would remove certain properties from the object type.

It should work this way:

```
type ObjectType = { 
    key1: number, 
    key2: string, 
    key3: boolean, 
    key4: number[] 
}

let obj: Remove<ObjectType, 'key2' | 'key4'>
```

Here `obj`'s type should be: { key1: number, key3: boolean }

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If we need to remove properties `key2` and `key4`, this will work:

```
type Without<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

let obj: Without<ObjectType, 'key2' | 'key4'>
```

**Elaboration:**

`Exclude<keyof T, K>` returns `'key1' | 'key3'`

`Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>` returns the desired result `{ key1: number, key3: boolean }`

Comment: You can simplify `keyof Pick<T, K>` to just `K`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! Corrected.

Answer (score 28):

As of TypeScript 3.5, there is an `Omit` helper that works as you describe.

```js
type ObjectType = { 
    key1: number, 
    key2: string, 
    key3: boolean, 
    key4: number[] 
}

let obj: Omit<ObjectType, 'key2' | 'key4'> // type is { key1: number, key3: boolean }
```

---

For older versions of TypeScript (>2.8), you can use a combination of `Pick` and `Exclude` as mentioned by Eduard in his answer.

I often make a helper type to make things a bit less verbose (note this is the exact definition used in TS 3.5)

```js
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Comment: Oddly enough, `Omit` allows you to omit fields not in the original, i.e., in the example above, `let obj: Omit<ObjectType, 'foo' | 'bar'>` compiles leaving `obj` with type `ObjectType`. If you want to ensure the fields you omit make sense, modify the definition: `type ExactOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;` (i.e., change `any` to `T`).

Comment: There is an issue where it forced my key that is possibly undefined to be omitted as well

Comment: @CyberMew can you provide a repro? It seems to be working as expected when I do as you describe. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=31&pln=7&pc=32#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwFBSgOwK4C2cEATgFy6HEkDcWUA9mMAJYM4CGANgPwX5FS9BgRbB+VIQF8MGUJCgkIAZzxdgKWKOAAeeAgA0UAOQixxgHxA

Comment: @JosiahNunemaker I have created a sample here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEFUG9ir65JAewFdIAuVAZwhnAHMBuXfBCaAWwAcIrKa6YJsAC+oSLEQpUAIWws8AIxAAbFZRz4tqMAg5R+tBsy0jUAH1RkAJlDjgo1xqgD0L1AHkeIIrpUA6UXFoeGQ0AGF5LWIJCijtPGgADwhDQWFTIIgATy40ABFUAF4MVAAyVEiKmWYcvNQAUWLSivDmKCSuIhgIVDq0ADFmwssG5mB+1AAJZo8OEAgAHgGAGlQAIkJSSHWAPmYYmmoifQA1BBhKGZLNVnYobl5KdfWVhVRlNUobOwdrNbcHxgRAA1lAwKgABawNBkFRQKhUVDEDj6CTWVCkCDvGLQOK3BLJVIbdbvMR4EQmZG+KhEeH+FREegAClpZwuAEpGEA

Comment: @CyberMew I believe that, in your case, you are running into the issue because `F` (and therefore `H`) is a union of `D` and `E`, the latter of which doesn't have a `bill` property. If E had a bill property, it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info @JosiahNunemaker, I reported the issue and the answer was: Omit is not a conditional type, so it doesn't distribute over unions. It's using keyof, which for union types only returns the keys common to all types of the union. That's where properties are "lost".

Comment: @CyberMew That is the proper behavior for `Omit`, and indeed, how most of TS works on union types.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'utility-types' Omit generic.

```
import { Omit } from "utility-types"

interface IHouse {
    rooms: number 
    gardenSize: number
    toilets: number
}

type Appartment = Omit<IHouse, "gardenSize">
```